# Overriding TextField color in MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get the border color to change from that default purple to white.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
        darkModeColorInput: {
            color: WHITE
        },
        darkModeColorLabel: {
            color: WHITE,
            "&:after": {
                borderColor: WHITE
            }
        }
    }));

    <TextField
    margin="normal"
    inputProps={{
        className: classes.darkModeColorInput
    }}
    InputLabelProps={{
        className: classes.darkModeColorLabel
    }}
    required
    fullWidth
    id="email"
    label="handle or email"
    name="email"
    autoComplete="email"
    autoFocus
    color={WHITE}
    />
```

This renders:

[image: img]

The label also switches from white to that default purple on focus. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the dark theme through the `ThemeProvider`:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'dark',
  },
});

<ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
   <Component />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Then, you will get a theme for all Material UI components that will show correctly on a dark background.

- https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/
- https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/

If you still want to fully control the look (and don't want to use a theme), you need to set custom styles for `InputLabelProps` and `InputProps` on your `TextInput` (https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/).

Comment: Do I use this wrapper in App.js or in every individual component .js?

Comment: You need it at the level you want to switch to dark mode.  App.js would work fine.